# SPSS - How to rank multiple variables by repeated measuring

Tags: ranking, spss, repeat

I have the following question: I have my data which looks like this:

```
UserId |Act1 |Act2 |Act3 |Act4
1      | 2   |  3  | 2   | 2
1      | 2   |  5  | 1   | 0
1      | 0   |  3  | 3   | 0
2      | 2   |  2  | 3   | 0
2      | 2   |  2  | 2   | 2
2      | 1   |  2  | 1   | 5
...
999    | 1   |  2  | 2   | 3
```

I want to rank amount of activities for every case and create a variable “Strategy”. If Act1 is the highest one of Act1, ACT2, ACT3, and Act4, then "Strategy" should be equal to "1". If Act2 is higher, then "Strategy" should be equal to "2", and so on. I have the same UserId's since I have made repeated measuring of the same variable (in this example 3 times).
How should the SPSS Syntax Code look like? Can I make a loop through every case (even if UserId is the same) to define a strategy that my users used in the experiment on this turn? Ideas?

Thanks,
Best,
Eugene

Comment: I'm not quite sure from your description how you do the ranking. So for `UserId` 1 is `Act2` the highest because the sum of the rows is the largest (e.g. `For UserID=1, Act2 = 3 + 5 + 3 = 11`)? Also most ranking strategies will need to specify how to deal with ties.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the solution for my own problem. It looks like this:

```
/*Computing strategy*/


/*Calculating dominant action*/

LOOP #i=1 TO 999. /*Assuming I have 999 cases.

/* Calculating the biggest value among activities.
  VECTOR #act(4). /* This is a temporary array variable.
  COMPUTE #act(1) = Act1.
  COMPUTE #act(2) = Act2.
  COMPUTE #act(3) = Act3.
  COMPUTE #act(4) = Act4.

/*Bubble sorting the numbers.
   LOOP #j=1 to 3.
      LOOP #k=#j+1 TO 4.
         DO IF (#act(#k) >= #act(#j)). 

            COMPUTE #temp = #k.
            COMPUTE #act(#j) = #act(#k).
            COMPUTE #act(#k) = #temp.            

         END IF.
     END LOOP.
/*At this point we have the biggest value in the first position of the array variable, i.e. "#act(1)".




/*Here I check whether the specific action is equal to the highest score.       
     VECTOR #strat(4).
     COMPUTE #strat(1) = Act1.
     COMPUTE #strat(2) = Act2.
     COMPUTE #strat(3) = Act3.
     COMPUTE #strat(4) = Act4.

/*Here I create 2 temporary variables to fix the result.
    COMPUTE #temp1 = 0.
    COMPUTE #temp2 = 0.
/*Next step is hard to explain, but: firstly, an participant could use two strategies, which is ok; secondly, if a participant uses more than 2 strategies, I assume he was acting not strategicaly (it comes from my research design, it may not fit to yours; e.g. Act1 = 0, Act2 = 0, Act3 = 0, Act4=0; or all actions are euqal to 3).
        LOOP #m=1 TO 4.
            DO IF (#strat(#m) = #act(1)). 
               DO IF (#temp1 = 0).
                  COMPUTE #temp1 = #m. /* If the variable has the highest value it is assumed to be a strategy; the value is stored in the variable "#temp1".
               ELSE.
                  DO IF (#temp2=0). /*if the first strtegy is assigned, then the second temporry variable is used, "#temp2".
                     COMPUTE #temp2 = #m.
                  ELSE.
                     COMPUTE #temp1 = 0. /*If all more than 2 variables have "highest" score, than no strategy was played; both temporary variables are defined as 0.
                     COMPUTE #temp2 = 0.
                  END IF.
               END IF.
            END IF.

        END LOOP.
/*And finally we create variables which are stored in our dataset and prescribe them values of our temporary variables.
         COMPUTE DominantStrategy1 = #temp1.
         COMPUTE DominantStrategy2 = #temp2.

   END LOOP.
END CASE. /*Making the same with the next case.
END LOOP.

EXECUTE.
```

This was my solution and it seems to work!

Best,
Eugen